# Missing numerals in Noto Color Emoji font

Tags: 16.04, gnome, emoji

I have used the following `fonts.conf` in Ubuntu 16.10 Unity to apply noto color emoji systemwide:

```
<!-- First install Noto Color Emoji font in ~/home/.fonts, then copy this file to
~/home/.config/fontconfig. This will set default emoji font to Noto Color Emoji font systemwide -->

<fontconfig>
<match>
    <test name="family"><string>sans-serif</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
        <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
</match>

<match>
    <test name="family"><string>serif</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
        <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
</match>
<match>
    <test name="family"><string>monospace</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
        <string>Emoji One Color</string>
    </edit>
</match>
<match>
    <test name="family"><string>Apple Color Emoji</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
        <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

But now in 16.04.2 GNOME, I'm facing a new kind of problem. All the numerals disappear when I place this `.conf` in its place. The clock, for example has no numbers:

[image: Missing numbers]

And same with calender, battery and everywhere there's a numeral. How can I make the system show numerals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that we are making the `Noto Color Emoji` the default font for `serif` and `sans-serif` fonts, and `Noto Color Emoji` font doesn't have glyph for numerals. We have to remove those lines from the `fonts.conf` file, and add the lines which makes the mentioned font as "preferred" font, which can be overridden when it can't render other text properly:

```
<alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
        </prefer>
</alias>
```

This will let you see Color Emojis everywhere without removing the numerals or spaces.