# Numbers disappeared in taskbar and notifications

Tags: 16.04, gnome, notification, taskbar

I have a weird issue. And I don't even know how to debug it.

I can't determine when this issue happened. One day i booted my computer and the issue was here.

Only the numbers are missing in the taskbar and all of the notifications. Example of taskbar :[image: Example of taskbar]

I tried different fonts for the system. Result is the same.
I have `TaskBar` extension installed. Tried removing it. Result is still same.

I don't know where to look. Any help is appreciated.

Ubuntu version:

`lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial`

Gnome Shell version:

`gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.18.5`

Comment: Maybe a corruption of desktop theme or font. try to change it using unity-twear-tool or gnome-tweak-tool, according to your GUI scheme.

Comment: @Redbob, nope, already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `Noto Color Emoji` font. The solution can be read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904909/missing-numerals-in-noto-color-emoji-font).