# Emoji can not show in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, emoji

In firefox, it can show emoji. But in gedit, fcitx, or gnome-characters, it can not show.

[Gnome-characters-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQgz6.png)

I have already install font `fonts-noto-color-emoji`. And I had follow [This Question's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029661/18-04-color-emoji-not-showing-up-at-all-in-chrome-only-partially-in-firefox). But the problem still has.

ps: My computer is from Ubuntu 16.04 to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04. But my laptop install Ubuntu 18.04, it is show emoji fine. So it is so weird. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu (熱烈歓迎), does these https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130880/color-emojis-working-partially-on-18-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029661/18-04-color-emoji-not-showing-up-at-all-in-chrome-only-partially-in-firefox/1196561#1196561 help?

Comment: @Sadaharu Wakisaka Thank you very much for your commit. I have tried, but the problem still has. The brower (Firefox & Chrome) show the emoji very well. But the other application, like gnome-characters & gedit, can not show.

Comment: Then this https://askubuntu.com/questions/904909/missing-numerals-in-noto-color-emoji-font?rq=1, or wait for 20.04 will arrive, a few weeks by now.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I have tried the link, the problem is not resolved. I will waiting for the 20.04. Thank you for your reply.